# $L^2(X,D)$ subspace of $L^2(X,A)$ being $D \subset A $

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to see the conditional probabiliy as a ortogonal Projection. For this purpose, if I have a sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$, consider the measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal {A}, \mu) $ with $\mu (\Omega) = 1$. Now if I have a smaller sigma algebra $\mathcal{D} \subset \mathcal{A}$, then I would like to see $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega, \mathcal{D})$ as a subspace of $\mathcal{L}^2(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$.

If I forget the equivalence relation this spaces have then is extremely clear, otherwise I am stuck trying to see that the smaller space is included in the greater space because given an element of the smaller space, i.e, a set of functions modulo 0, I cant see if this coset will be greater as a coset of the greater space and hence distinct. More explicity, if I take $ [f]_s $, where $[]_s $ stands for the coset of $f $ in the smaller space, then I would like to see that $[f]_g = [f]_s$ being $[f]_g$ the coset of $f$ in the greater space. If this happens then I have proved that the smaller space is included in the greater.

Of course one can always view a copy of the smaller space in the greater space sending $[f]_s \to [f]_g$, but this is mot what I want at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sets it is not true that $L^{2}(X,D)$ is a subset of $L^{2}(X,A)$.

Elements of $L^{2}(X,D)$ are equivalence classes if $D-$ measurable functions under equality a.e.. If $f \in L^{2}(X,D)$ then any representative of $f$ is $D-$ measurable and hence also $A-$ measurable. If $g$ and $h$ are $D-$ measurable functions in the same equivalence class  then $\{x:g(x)=h(x)\}$ is in the sigma algebra $D$ and hence also in $A$. Thus $g=h$ as elements of  $L^{2}(X,A)$. This gives a well-defined map which is linear; it is, in fact, an isometric isomorphism.

Comment: Yes of course, but what you have proved is that the map $[f]_s \to [f]_g $ is well defined. But what I want to see is that there are no more functions in the equivalence class!, i.e, when you look a the equivañence class in the greater sigma algebra then you do not find new functions

Comment: There may be functions that are $A-$ measurable but not $D-$ meaurable in the equivalence class.  That does not affect the fact that $L^{2}(X,D)$ can be 'considered' as a subset of $L^{2}(X,D)$ . What is important is the following: with each equivalence class $[f]$  w.r.t. $D$ we can associate an equivalence w.r.t. $A$ and the map which takes the first equivalence class to the second is linear isometric isomorphism. Set theoretically, is is **not true** that $L^{2}(X,D)$ is a subset of $L^{2}(X,A)$.

Comment: Great!!! I want to confirm that last sentence. Set theoretically, is not true! At first I try to give a prove that was true, then I was convinced that not! But I did not thought a counterexample, i can admit that it was vague on my part. Maybe this is a clear counterxample: Consider $X = \mathbb{R}$ $A = P(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mu = \delta$ the Dirac measure, i.e, $\delta(E) = 1$ if 0 belongs to E, and if not $\delta(E) = 0$. Then $f = g \ a.e$ if and only if $f(0) = g(0)$. Now consider  $B(\mathbb{R})$ then is clear that there are more functions in the equivalence class. What do you think?

Comment: You are right. You can also take $D$ to be the trivial sigma algebra to construct such examples easily.

Comment: Great! Definitly it was vague on my part, sorry, thanks for your time!